# Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String

Tags: vb.net

I want to use a filter on my datagridview according to the below method:

```
 dt = ExecuteSelect(QueryCondition, IDWindow).Tables(0)
        _textFilters = ""

            Dim first As Boolean = True

            For Each f As field In fields
                If f.Value.Length > 0 Then

                    If Not first Then
                        _textFilters += " and "
                    End If
                _textFilters &=  f.Field &  " like '%" & f.Value & "%'"
                    first = False
                End If
        Next

        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = _textFilters
```

I got the error in the line

```
 dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = _textFilters
```

Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String

because i have some decimal fields in my database table.

But if i use:

```
 Dim view As DataView = New DataView(grille.DataSource)
_textFilters = ""
Dim first As Boolean = True
 For Each f As field In fields
                If f.Value.Length > 0 Then
                If Not first Then
                    _textFilters += " and "
                End If
                Select Case f.Field.GetType.ToString
                    Case "String"
                        _textFilters &= f.Field & " like '%" & f.Value & "%'"
                    Case "DateTime"
                    Case Else
                        _textFilters &= f.Field & ">=" & f.Value
                End Select

                    first = False
                End If
        Next

        view.RowFilter = _textFilters
```

The code doesnt send an error but the filter doesn't work .

Hope I'm clear

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the type of `f.Field` and `f.Value`?

Comment: numeric(18,0) so i guess that they are decimal

Comment: No need to guess, just hover over the variable in debugger. BTW, regarding your implementation, you can simplify your code a lot, if you store filters in a list of string, and then do `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Join(" and ", yourFilterList)`

Comment: Thanks @Neolisk for your reply.still not working.I edited my  question by adding the code i changed by testing on the type of field.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what's the value of `_textFilters`? You can view it in debugger. Put a breakpoint on `view.RowFilter = _textFilters` and tell me the value of `_textFilters`.

Comment: @Neolisk I already view it in the debugger and it's correct(numéro>=2).I changed my dataview by Dim view As DataView = CType(grille.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView and it works now.Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh yeah, I did not notice you are creating a view on the side and then not doing anything with it. BTW, if `grille` is your DataTable, you can also do `grille.DefaultView.RowFilter = `, less typing involved. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Like operator is purely for stings. If you want to filter on a decimal data type you should use one of the following operators: <, >, =.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes indeed.That's  why i convert my fields to string with  _textFilters &= "Convert(" & f.Field & ", 'System.String') " & " like '%" + f.Value & "%'"  but i didnt get my datagridview filtered

Comment: I am assuming that .Net translates the filter to SQL and executes it against the DB - this is perhaps why your convert did not work.

Comment: @Donal: DataTable's filtering works independently from the database backend, with its own syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Donal for your reply.You're right we can't use like for decimal data type so I changed my source code.I edited my  question by adding the code i changed by testing on the type of field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming f.Field is of a numeric type, using the `ToString` method should work:

```
_textFilters &=  f.Field.ToString() &  " like '%" & f.Value & "%'"
```